# styling wordpress menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, styling

I am trying to style a navigation menu i created using some css. I want the menu background colour to change when the use hovers over the menu item.
The menu is called 'side-bar-menu'

The difficulty I am having is making the background colour fill the menu item when hovered.The background colour of the link changes, but i doesn't fill the actual menu item. I've tried padding, which sort of works but it doesn't correctly fill the menu item.... help

This is my css so far:-

```
/* The SideBar menu styling*/
#menu-side-bar-menu li  {
list-style-type: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
background-color: #f2f1f1;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

#menu-side-bar-menu a {
color: #BA9E2F;
}

#menu-side-bar-menu li a:hover { 
background: #BA9E2F !important;
color: #fff; 
padding-top:8px;
padding-bottom:9px;
}
```

This is a [link](http://www.golfattitude.co.uk/pontefractGC/course-overview/) to the page I'm trying to style. Its the menu down the left of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 things to do:

1.) remove the `padding` from `#menu-side-bar-menu li` completely

2.) Add the padding you had for `li` to `#menu-side-bar-menu a` and also add `display: block` to it to have `li` fully filled by `a`

3.) Remove the `padding` from the `#menu-side-bar-menu li a:hover` rule to avoid a change in size when hovering.

This results in the following CSS:

```
#menu-side-bar-menu li  {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
  background-color: #f2f1f1;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

#menu-side-bar-menu a {
  display: block;
  color: #BA9E2F;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

#menu-side-bar-menu li a:hover { 
  background: #BA9E2F !important;
  color: #fff; 
}
```

Comment: Absolutely Perfect.It works a treat... thank you VERY much  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.sub-menu li {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

It worked in the inspector.